# Is there a way to restrict a program (.exe) from opening firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Everytime I run this one program (.exe) it opens Firefox. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: Don't run that program.

Comment: Put the program in one domain, Firefox in another domain, and explicitly deny transitions from the one domain to the other. Oh, whoops... wrong OS.

Comment: I just want to know if there is anyway to restrict the program it is an autoit executable i know what it does and it is safe but i dont want it to open firefox everytime it starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you an answer with as little info as you're giving. but one possibility might be autoruns:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

It can help you by being able to disable just about any auto running program. you might have to dig around a little bit to find the right check box (there are a lot of them).

The other possibility is you can go into control panel -> default programs -> set associations. whence there, check to make sure that .exe isn't associated with Firefox for some odd odd reason.